# Given an array of various colored balls placed in circular, delete the same consecutive colored balls and print the non consecutive colored balls

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The array will be arranged in a circular form and the consecutive same colored balls should be removed and again should form the circle and remove the same consecutive colored balls. Finally print the individual balls without any consecutive colors in the array.

```
'''input
'''
arr = ["red", "white", "black", "black", "white", "blue", "red"]

'''output
["blue"]
'''
```

Comment: You can store them in a stack and remove all the same adjacent elements in the first run. In the second run you can start from like say the middle of the list and go to left till you reach the start and then go to right most and do the same procedure as you did in first run.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
def has_consecutive_duplicates(arr):
    changed = True

    if len(arr) == 1:
        return False
    for i,color in enumerate(arr):
        try:
            next_color = arr[i+1]
        except Exception:
            next_color = arr[0]

        if color == next_color:

            if next_color == arr[0]:
                arr.remove(arr[0])
                arr.remove(color)
            else:
                arr.remove(next_color)
                arr.remove(arr[i])


            return changed
    else:
        print("All done")
        changed = False

return changed

while True:
    if not has_consecutive_duplicates(arr):
        break
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of strings, list of integers, list of floats or a mixed list with string and integers and floats, you can use :

```
import itertools as itr

def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

def groupCosecutive(lst):
    return [list(x[1]) for x in itr.groupby(lst)]

def remCircular(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    lst = list(map(str, lst))
    while True:
        lst  = groupCosecutive(lst)
        if set(lst[0])==set(lst[-1]):
            lst = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) < 2, lst[1:-1]))
            lst = list(itr.chain(*lst))
        else :
            lst = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) < 2, lst))
            lst = list(itr.chain(*lst))

        if len(lst) <= 1:
            break

        elif sum(map(len, groupCosecutive(lst))) == len(groupCosecutive(lst)) and set(lst[0]) != set(lst[-1]):
            break

    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else float(x) if isfloat(x) else x for x in lst]

print(remCircular(your_list))
```

input : `["red", "white", "black", "black", "white", "blue", "red"]`
output : `['blue']`
input : `[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2]`
output : `[3,5,1]`
input : `[2.2, "red", "white", "black", "black", 1, 9, 9, 3.987, 2.2]`
output : `['red', 'white', 1, 3.987]`